# Intermittent "file not found" errors when compiling c++ under multipass Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: c++, multipass

I am trying to use multipass to spawn a build environment, the source code being on the host machine.  The idea is that I would mount the source code from the host into the VM and then run the build from inside the VM. (`multipass mount src ubuntu:/home/ubuntu/src`).

What I am trying to build is a relatively large c++ project with lots of include files. The build system is CMake + ninja and clang 8.0.

The problem is that the build fails with "file not found" errors for various headers. Each time the "missing" file is different. I say "missing" because the files are all actually there.

This seemed exactly the same as [Intermittent, random 'file not found' errors under Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50206890/intermittent-random-file-not-found-errors-under-windows-subsystem-for-linux), but using the suggested workaround did not help (e.g. I tried setting -j1 in ninja).

Any idea of what could be causing this and if there is a workaround?

My host machine is a macOS Catalina and the multipass VM instance is a Ubuntu 20.10. multipass itself is 1.5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up [opening a PR](https://github.com/canonical/multipass/issues/1933) to the multipass team. After some debugging, we uncovered two problems:

1. macOS Catalina has a default `maxfiles` limit of 256, which can be hit when compiling large projects.
2. There is a limit in `libssh`, which is used by multipass to do the mounts.

**To workaround this**, you need to:

1. Increase the `maxfiles` limit in macOS by e.g. [following this](https://gist.github.com/devinrhode2/4cbf7f02a9701510d61f5be0515b8286)
2. Manually mount the folder by (1) installing `osxfuse` in macOS, (2) Enable Remote login in Settings -> Sharing and (3) in the VM

```
mkdir <mount_dir>
sshfs <host_user>@<host_ip>:<host_directory> <mount_dir>
```